# Webstorm: Why is "upload to default server" gray/deactivated?

Tags: ftp, webstorm, remote-host

I'm using the ftp client in Webstorm.
An ftp server is set up properly and I can browse it in the "Remote Host" tool window. Also the ftp server is set as default:
[image]

However, I cannot upload or download
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While posting this question I just noticed that my mappings were not set up properly:
[image: Mappings]
Both web-host and deployment path should have been specified.

(Maybe someone else is as stupid as me and will find this helpful.)